# Literate Agda in Markdown format to LaTeX via Pandoc

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, pandoc, agda, literate-programming

Agda supports Markdown for literate programming input, [as described here](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/literate-programming.html#literate-markdown): everything outside ```` ``` ```` and ```` ```agda ```` blocks is ignored by Agda, allowing you to load the same `.lagda.md` files into Agda and process them with Pandoc.

However, if Pandoc is used ultimately to target HTML output, then Agda can also be used do syntax highlighting and reference hyperlinking, as described in [Jespec Cockx's blog post](https://jesper.sikanda.be/posts/literate-agda.html): `agda --html` produces valid Markdown from Markdown input, with all Agda code blocks replaced by HTML fragments that apply syntax highlighting.

Is there a way to do the same, but targeting LaTeX instead of HTML? So I'd like to do the following:

1. Write Literate Agda in Markdown format in `MySource.lagda.md` file
2. Process `MySource.lagda.md` with Agda to get `Highlighted.md`
3. Process `Highlighted.md` with Pandoc, using the Beamer template, to produce `Final.pdf`.

I've tried using `agda --latex` for step 2, but its output file is byte-by-byte equal to the input file.

Comment: I posted an answer to the same question on the [Agda mailing list](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2019/011286.html). However, this [doesn't seem to produce the proper output](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2019/011288.html). So there is currently no easy way to do this AFAIK.